# DYNAMICALLY perform insert(inedex,data), delete(index), getAt(index) operations in Efficient time and memory.

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-arrays

Recently I have ***developed and IMPLEMENTED*** an algorithm which is performing following 4 operations in Non-Amortized O(log m) time , where m is the number of elements present in Memory=O(m).

1.>insert(int index,int data)::
 It inserts data at any index(just like in array)  randomly and dynamically but with different time complexity.It can be understood as inserting in an array at a particular index but main feature is that it can insert data at same index in  O(log m) time along with SHIFTING ALL data present contiguously from that index onwards .For eg:: insert any data as:
index ,data
{
(1    ,0),
(2    ,1),
(78   ,2),
(0    ,3),
(45   ,4),
(58999,5),
(32111,6),
(1    ,7),
(78   ,8),
(78   ,9),
(78   ,-1),
(0    ,-2),
(0    ,-3),
(0    ,-4),
(23   ,-5)
}. Then total time complexity for all insertions is O(log (m!) ), here m=15  and Memory= O(15).
NOTE:: NEW SEQUENCE OF DATA IS STORED as per my ALGORITHM AS:: 
{
(0,-4),
(1,-3),
(2,-2),
(3,3),
(4,7),
(5,0),
(6,1),
(23,-5),
(45,4),
(78,-1),
(79,9),
(80,8),
(81,2),
(32111,6),
(58999,5)
}.
**HERE INSERTION AT PREOCCUPIED INDEX IS ON SAME INDEX WITH SHIFTING ALL ELEMENTS ON and BEYOND THAT INDEX IN WORST-CASE OF (log m) time complexity.**

2.> delete(int index): 
It  deletes data ,if present , at index . Worst-Case Time is O(log m).

3.> getAt(int index):: 
It retrieves data ,if present, at index.Time in Worst-Case is O(log m).

4.> printAll():: It will print All elements(data) in increasing order of index.**Time in ALL CASES** is O(m),m= no. of elements present.
TIME COST::
Here Worst Case Time for each of Ist 3 operations is O(log m) at any time where m=no. of elements present at that time and for last one is O(m).
SPACE COST::
Space used is O(m), m= no. of elements present.
AS I HAVE THOROUGHLY SEARCHED ON INTERNET BUT NOT FOUND SOLUTIONS WITH SUCH OPTIMIZED TIME AND SPACE COST FOR ALL ABOVE STATED 4 OPERATIONS.

***I WANT TO KNOW WETHER SUCH TIME  AND MEMORY COST HAS BEEN ACHIEVED FOR ALL ABOVE 4 OPERATIONS BY ANYONE TILL NOW ,if not Can it be patented?
Also I cannot reveal anything about my algorithm more than this ....***

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really a specific programming question but rather a question about intellectual property as well as research into state of the art in computer science.

Comment: Yes, these bounds are well known to be achievable.

Comment: @Mr. David :: Can you Please share the link of that well known acheived algorithm or if no link , kindly share that algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible.
If we use ordered binary search tree then also for the above test cases it will take time as O(log 58999!) and space to be O(58999).
It is because all the empty nodes would have to be created for reaching last index .
Even if we use array then also we have to create array till 58999 index and moreover worst case insertion will take O(58989) time complexity.
@Gaara :Its amazing that  you have achieved O(log 15) time complexity in worst case but for getting a patent I truely don't know.As you will not reveal anything more about your algorithm...
@David Eisenstat: I also want to know how you will achieve it .